# Why it is not possible to define generic indexers in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Why can't you create a generic indexer in .NET?

the following code throws a compiler error:

```
public T this<T>[string key]
{
    get => /* Return generic type T. */
}
```

Does this mean you can't create a generic indexer for a generic member collection?

Comment: What usage syntax would you want? obj<Type>[i] looks like it would conflict with comparing obj to T, obj[i]<Type> is better, but I find it hard to read. My preference is obj[<Type>i], but not by much.

Comment: I fail to see why we wouldn't just want to use a generic method.  It's cleaner, IMO, as adding generics to indexes would lead to difficult-to-read code.

Comment: If it was implemented then `<T>` would be preceding to `this` as `public T <T>this[string key]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of this can be used is something along these lines:

```
var settings = ConfigurationSection.AppSettings;
var connectionString = settings<string>["connectionString"];
var timeout = settings<int>["timeout"];
```

But this doesn't actually buy you anything. You've just replaced round parentheses (as in `(int)settings["timeout"]`) with angle brackets, but received no additional type safety as you can freely do

```
var timeout = settings<int>["connectionString"];
```

If you have something that's strongly but not statically typed, you might want to wait until C# 4.0 with its *dynamic* keyword.

Comment: Well, actually the settings<int> syntax is preferable. C-style casts often forces you to include additional parenthesis.

Comment: @John  I agree.  I think that is nicer than creating method accessors like Filed<> and SetFiled<> in DataRow Class for example.

Comment: It would add type safety if reading `settings<int>["foo"]` would store the last thing written to `settings<int>["foo"]`, without regard for whether anything had been written to `settings<string>["foo"]` before or since.  The biggest thing to note about such a design is that after `settings<SiameseCat>["foo"] = someSiameseCat`, an attempt to read `settings<Animal>["foo"] would not see that cat, whereas after non-generic `settings["foo"] = someSiameseCat;` `myAnimal = (Animal)settings["SiameseCat"] would see it.

Answer (score 39):

Here's a place where this would be useful. Say you have a strongly-typed `OptionKey<T>` for declaring options.

```
public static class DefaultOptions
{
    public static OptionKey<bool> SomeBooleanOption { get; }
    public static OptionKey<int> SomeIntegerOption { get; }
}
```

Where options are exposed through the `IOptions` interface:

```
public interface IOptions
{
    /* since options have a default value that can be returned if nothing's
     * been set for the key, it'd be nice to use the property instead of the
     * pair of methods.
     */
    T this<T>[OptionKey<T> key]
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    T GetOptionValue<T>(OptionKey<T> key);
    void SetOptionValue<T>(OptionKey<T> key, T value);
}
```

Code could then use the generic indexer as a nice strongly-typed options store:

```
void Foo()
{
    IOptions o = ...;
    o[DefaultOptions.SomeBooleanOption] = true;
    int integerValue = o[DefaultOptions.SomeIntegerOption];
}
```

Comment: It's 2021 and we only have generic method but still no generic indexer...

Answer (score 19):

I don't know why, but indexers are just syntactic sugar. Write a generic method instead and you'll get the same functionality. For example:

```
   public T GetItem<T>(string key)
   {
      /* Return generic type T. */
   }
```

Comment: Note. Indexers are also used for the dictionary collection initialization (e.g. `new Dictionary<string, int> { ["key"] = 3 }` ). You cannot use an alternative for this I don't think.

Answer (score 17):

Properties can't be generic in C#2.0/3.0 so therefore you can't have a generic indexer.

Comment: Do you have a link to anything on that front? I can't see it in the "new features" document.

Comment: mmmm...I think I found the link you are looking for.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=352188

What It seems incredible to me is that Microsoft says it is not a useful feature but have already implemented some workaround extenders(i.e.DataRowExtender)

Comment: year 2016, c# 6 there is no generic indexer.
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/523

Answer (score 8):

You can; just drop the `<T>` part from your declaration and it will work fine. i.e.

```
public T this[string key]
{
   get { /* Return generic type T. */ }
}
```

(Assuming your class is generic with a type parameter named `T`).

Comment: @Igor - that's why I said "Assuming your class is generic with a type parameter named T". The question did not indicate that the type parameter should be different from the container (and in any case this would be a very unusual design!).

Comment: @Greg...how unusual can it be?  Take as an example the Field<> generic method in DataRow.  What they did is unboxing through a generic method since it is impossible through a generic indexer.

Comment: @Igor - it's the implication that's the issue. An indexer implies direct access to the actual object at that index, not a converted form of that object, whereas a method has no such implication. And just think of the syntax: someObject<int>["abc"] isn't very pretty.

Answer (score 3):

I like the ability to have an indexer without handing out
a direct reference to the "indexed" item. I wrote a simple
"call back" Indexer class below ...

R = the returned type from the indexer
P = the passed type into the indexer

All the indexer really does is pass the operations to
the deployer and allow them to manage what actually occurs
and gets returned.

```
public class GeneralIndexer<R,P>
    {
        // Delegates
        public delegate R gen_get(P parm);
        public delegate void gen_set(P parm, R value);
        public delegate P[] key_get();

        // Events
        public event gen_get GetEvent;
        public event gen_set SetEvent;
        public event key_get KeyRequest;

        public R this[P parm]
        {
            get { return GetEvent.Invoke(parm); }
            set { SetEvent.Invoke(parm, value); }
        }

        public P[] Keys
        {
            get
            {
                return KeyRequest.Invoke();
            }
        }

    }
```

To use it in a program or class:

```
private GeneralIndexer<TimeSpan, string> TimeIndex = new GeneralIndexer<TimeSpan,string>();

{
            TimeIndex.GetEvent += new GeneralIndexer<TimeSpan, string>.gen_get(TimeIndex_GetEvent);
            TimeIndex.SetEvent += new GeneralIndexer<TimeSpan, string>.gen_set(TimeIndex_SetEvent);
            TimeIndex.KeyRequest += new GeneralIndexer<TimeSpan, string>.key_get(TimeIndex_KeyRequest);

}
```

works like a champ especially if you want to monitor access to
your list or do any special operations when something is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

In recent C-sharp you can declare the return type as "dynamic".  This is the same as using "object" except that the C# runtime will allow you to use it in code as if it was the type you think it is and then check at run-time to be sure you were right...