# C# using indexers with templates

Tags: c#, indexer

I'm to trying to create a class to deal with loading in resources (textures, sounds etc). I am trying to create it so that I can do something similar to the following:

```
ContentHandler contentHandler=new ContentHandler(content);
Texture2D texture=contentHandler<Texture2D>["picture"];
```

The problem I am having is that while I can create the indexers just fine, I don't know how to use templates with it so that I can get a specific type passed to it. I could just use a regular template function, but I'd MUCH rather use the above if it's possible. I've tried searching but I have a hard time coming up with anything.

Comment: Please...not template, its a generic.

Comment: Sorry felix, used to C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your question is really:

> Can I write a generic indexer?

If that's the case, the answer is no. You'd have to write a method instead:

```
Texture2D texture = contentHandler.GetValue<Texture2D>("picture");
```

Also note that generics *aren't* templates. It's worth being very clear on that :)

Comment: Generic indexers would be crazy stuff of course. Imagine what crap you can do with them ( even generic properties ).

Comment: Dang I was scared it wasn't implemented. Just would be so much cleaner with a generic indexer. Thanks though, I guess I'll just use have to use methods to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your a looking for [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Possible duplicate: [Why it is not possible to define generic indexers in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494827/why-it-is-not-posible-to-define-generic-indexers-in-net)

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking to use with the indexer property. The class itself can't be generic however because it's a singleton. I do not want 40 different classes for 40 different kinds of resources. I would like to make the method generic, but I can't figure out how to make a generic indexer (sorry for calling it templates, I learned C++ first)

Comment: As Jon Skeet already mentioned you can create a generic method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(v=vs.80).aspx