# C#: Exposing type safe API over heterogeneous dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, containers

I'd like to expose a type safe API over a particular JSON format. Here is basically what I have so far:

```
public class JsonDictionary
{
    Dictionary<string, Type> _keyTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>  {
        { "FOO", typeof(int) },
        { "BAR", typeof(string) },
        };
    IDictionary<string, object> _data;
    public JsonDictionary()
    {
        _data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    public void Set<T>(string key, T obj)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != _keyTypes[key])
            throw new Exception($"Invalid type: {typeof(T)} vs {_keyTypes[key]}");
        _data[key] = obj;
    }

    public dynamic Get(string key)
    {
        var value = _data[key];
        if (value.GetType() != _keyTypes[key])
            throw new Exception($"Invalid type: {value.GetType()} vs {_keyTypes[key]}");
        return value;
    }
}
```

Which can be used nicely as:

```
JsonDictionary d = new JsonDictionary();
d.Set("FOO", 42);
d.Set("BAR", "value");
```

However reading the value is a little disapointing and rely on late binding:

```
var i = d.Get("FOO");
var s = d.Get("BAR");
Assert.Equal(42, i);
Assert.Equal("value", s);
```

Is there some C# magic that I can use to implement a type-safe generic `Get<T>` instead of relying on `dynamic` here (ideally type should be checked at compilation time) ? I'd like to also use the pattern for `Set<T>` so that `d.Set("BAR", 56);` triggers a compilation warning.

---

`Dictionary<string, Type> _keyTypes` can be made `static` if needed. The above is just work in progress.

Comment: What type would `d.Get(new Random().NextDouble() > 0.5 ? "FOO" : "BAR")` return?

Comment: It should equal `typeof(_keyTypes[key])` in this case

Comment: But the compiler must know the type of that expression at compile time though (if you want compile-time type checking). `typeof(_keyTypes[key])` is not something that the compiler can know. The check has to be done at runtime, but it doesn't have to be `dynamic`. Have you considered doing something similar to what you did with `Set`?

Comment: Using C++ metaprogramming you can derive a `type` from an `enum`, isn't it possible in C# ?

Comment: No. C# is not C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using solution similar to this:

```
public class JsonDictionary
{
    public static readonly Key<int> Foo = new Key<int> { Name = "FOO" };
    public static readonly Key<string> Bar = new Key<string> { Name = "BAR" };
        
    IDictionary<string, object> _data;
    public JsonDictionary()
    {
        _data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    
    public void Set<T>(Key<T> key, T obj)
    {
        _data[key.Name] = obj;
    }

    public T Get<T>(Key<T> key)
    {
        return (T)_data[key.Name];
    }
    
    public sealed class Key<T>
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant ! Thanks

Comment: The next step is a generic indexer as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178769/136285

Answer (score -1):

I would convert T to object and check object type with .GetType()

```
public class JsonDictionary
    {
        Dictionary<string, Type> _keyTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>  {
        { "FOO", typeof(int) },
        { "BAR", typeof(string) },
        };
        IDictionary<string, object> _data;
        public JsonDictionary()
        {
            _data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
        public void Set(string key, object obj)
        {
            if (obj.GetType() != _keyTypes[key])
                throw new Exception($"Invalid type: {obj.GetType()} vs {_keyTypes[key]}");
            _data[key] = obj;
        }

        public object Get(string key)
        {
            return _data[key];
        }
    }
```

I tried it like this and it worked:

```
JsonDictionary d = new JsonDictionary();
d.Set("FOO", 42);
d.Set("BAR", "value");

var i = d.Get("FOO");
var s = d.Get("BAR");
Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

But to be honest, I don't like what you are trying to achieve.